# Android send SMS fail because of 160 character limit but sent as multipart

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

Some of my clients (~100) are reporting that the SMS is not being sent by the app. So I have added debug logs in the app and the following error comes:

```
(1) RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE (Generic failure cause)
```

According to the docs, the source of the error can't be identified, maybe the device didn't had network, airplaine mode was on, etc.

This is how the SMS are being sent:

```
   private void sendSMS(@NonNull String phoneNumber, @NonNull String message, @Nullable PendingIntent pendingIntentSent, @Nullable PendingIntent pendingIntentDelivered) {
        SmsManager smsManager = null;

        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                int smsId = SmsManager.getDefaultSmsSubscriptionId();
                smsManager = SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(smsId);
            }
            else {
                smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (smsManager == null)
            smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

        ArrayList<String> messageDivided = smsManager.divideMessage(message);
        if (messageDivided.size() == 1) {
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pendingIntentSent, pendingIntentDelivered)
        }
        else {
            ArrayList<PendingIntent> piSentList = null;
            ArrayList<PendingIntent> piDeliveredList = null;

            if (pendingIntentSent != null) {
                piSentList = new ArrayList<>();
            }

            if (pendingIntentDelivered != null) {
                piDeliveredList = new ArrayList<>();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < messageDivided.size(); i++) {
                if (pendingIntentSent != null)
                    piSentList.add(pendingIntentSent);

                if (pendingIntentDelivered != null)
                    piDeliveredList.add(pendingIntentDelivered);
            }

            smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, messageDivided, piSentList, piDeliveredList);
        }
    }
```

What have I figured out that if the message length is less than 160 characters, the error disappears and the SMS can be sent successfully. However, this is a partial fix, because I don't want that my users to limit the SMS.

Also the SMS length limit is different from carrier to carrier.

**US Cellular**:

> Each text message is limited to 150 characters, including spaces and
>   punctuation. If a message is longer than 150 characters, the remainder
>   will be lost, resulting in incomplete messages being received. Note:
>   Some handsets may have a smaller character limit.

Other network operators have different SMS length, 140 or 160.

Comment: Some carriers also don't handle multipart messages. Have you checked that with the users having issues?

Comment: I think it's exactly the issue that I'm having. If the SMS length is greater than 160 length, then the SMS can be sent in multipart but the mobile operator automatically rejects the message.

Comment: Yeah, I've never been on one that doesn't handle multipart, so I'm not sure how that works on the user end, exactly. I would guess that their SMS apps just don't let them compose a message longer than the max length of a single message. I know there's a method that will let you know how a message will be split, if it's longer, but I'm not sure if it will tell you the maximum number of parts supported by the carrier. I'll do some digging through the source code later on, when I get a chance.

Comment: ...but the settings there didn't match the actual behavior, so who knows where the values are actually coming from. Anyway, you might want to try to confirm that this really is the issue with those users who're having problems, before you put too much effort into a fix. Beyond that, you might just have to add some sort of warning to your UI; e.g., something that pops up when a message is going over the limit that says "This may fail...".

Comment: Lastly, the method I mentioned earlier is [`SmsMessage.html#calculateLength()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html#calculateLength(java.lang.String,%20boolean)). It returns some useful stats, but there's no part limit considered. It pretty much takes any length of string, and just does the raw calculations. I would think, though, it should at least give you a definite max for a single part message on a given device, provided that they set the SMS constants correctly.

Comment: Oh, shoot. I was just coming back to see if you'd gotten my comments, and my fat fingers accidentally deleted one. Sorry 'bout that, but it looks like you got a chance to read them all, at least. If I come across anything useful in the near future, I'll let ya know.

Comment: What protocol are you using sending SMS to the carrier ?